# Save the text in multiline textbox after clicking on label in c#

Tags: c#, textbox, label

I have three labels red,yellow and blue. After clicking on the red label in textbox is showing a text "You click on the red label" but after clicking on yellow label the text is changed on "You click on the yellow label" i need a code where i can save and synchronize all the clicks from the label into multiline textbox.
I am new in learning C#
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

First you should create **three** **Labels** and **one** **richTextBox** at the Form1 and then use the below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WinFormsApp_TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            
        }


        private List<string> saveClicks = new List<String>();

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveClicks.Add("You click on the red label");

            richTextBox1.Lines = saveClicks.ToArray();

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveClicks.Add("You click on the blue label");

            richTextBox1.Lines = saveClicks.ToArray();
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveClicks.Add("You click on the yellow label");

            richTextBox1.Lines = saveClicks.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about multiline textbox and not richTextbox?

Comment: @Mil create e StringBuilder for ex. `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textbox1.Text);` and then use at the labels:  `sb.AppendLine("You click on the yellow label");` in Label1 `sb.AppendLine("You click on the blue label");` in Label2  `sb.AppendLine("You click on the red label");` in Label3 and at the end `textbox1.Text = sb.ToString();`